# Localhost vs ip-address (e.g. 192.xxx.x.xxx)

Tags: apache, localhost, ip-address, phpwebsocket

When I host a page in `/var/www/page`, I can view it via:

- `localhost/page`
- `192.xxx.x.xxx/page`

Recently, I have started playing with websockets (using [this repository](https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat)).

When I activate the server, I can connect using `localhost/page` but not with `192.xxx.x.xxx/page` (note that I can access the page but not connect to the server)

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Echo out this and see what you get `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

Comment: yes apache, from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; i get 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "On most computer systems, localhost resolves to the address 127.0.0.1, which is the most-commonly used IPv4 loopback address..." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)

It's likely that the "localhost" host name is being resolved to the loopback interface IP address (127.0.0.1), as that is the standard on most machines.

If you want the server to respond to another IP address, you'll have to configure it.

Comment: so theoretically if i change this line: $Server->wsStartServer('localhost', 9300); to $Server->wsStartServer('<my ip address here>', 9300); should that make it accessable using via 192.xxx.x.xxx/page?

Comment: Yes, localhost is (to my knowledge) always resolved to the IP address 127.0.0.1.